# Should there be a space after / before a css child selector?

Tags: css

Does it make a difference to have a space behind or before a css child combinator `>`?
Is this:

```
foo > bar {}
```

Any different from this?

```
foo>bar {}
```

Comment: it's the same but the first one is more clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Makes no Difference at All - Kinda

Makes no difference at all. You could argue taking the spaces out (minifying) will speed up performance, but that would only help large busy sites. For most people, they would prefer the readability of the spaces for a better understanding of the code, especially when working in teams. For minification, that should be done by an external application.

```css
.foo div>p{color:#fff;background:blue;width:100px;height:100px;}
.boo div > p {color:#fff; background:red; width:100px; height:100px;}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="foo"><div><p>FOO</p></div></div>
<div class="boo"><div><p>BOO</p></div></div>
</body>
```